# Android getServerAuthCode() without extra permissions

Tags: android, permissions, google-play-games, scopes

I'm trying to authenticate an Android user with a backend server:

- the app calls `getServerAuthCode()` and forwards the authorization code using HTTPS to our BE
- the BE exchanges the server authorization code for an access token using GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest
- the BE passes the access token to  www.googleapis.com/games/v1/applications which returns the *playerId* (that's all I really need, I don't care for email and other user information)

The procedure is outlined here:

- https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html (2016)

and here

- https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/12/games-authentication-adopting-google.html (2017)

If I use the the instruction from 2017 I'm able to getServerAuthCode() without requesting any extra permissions. The only permission is: Google Play / Manage your game activity for this game. This is possible by specifying `GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN` which is available on by using play-service 10.2.1. I'm unable to use 10.2.1 because of 3rd party dependencies.

The 2016 article explains how to `getServerAuthCode()` the '*old*' way (using play-services 9.6.1), but I'm not able to get by without requesting some extra permissions.

If I do it like this, I get the asked for "Know who you are on google":

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestServerAuthCode(serverClientId)
    .requestScopes(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
    .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
    .build();

        ...

protected void onActivityResult(int request, int response, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(request, response, data);

    if (request == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            String authCode = acct.getServerAuthCode();
        }
```

If I remove `.requestServerAuthCode(serverClientId)` from gso, authCode is null.

Another thing I tried (using only Games.API sign in):

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this)
    .addApi(Games.API)
    .build();

...

Games.GetServerAuthCodeResult result = Games.getGamesServerAuthCode(mGoogleApiClient, serverClinetId).await();

if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
    String authCode = result.getCode();
```

I get `result.getStatus().isSuccess()=false` and `result.getStatus().getStatusMessage()` returns `STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED (2)`. In the logs I see:

```
[GetToken] GetToken failed with status code: NeedPermission
04-10 14:27:41.764: W/GamesServerAuthCodeOp(5775): Failed to retrieve the server auth code
04-10 14:27:41.764: W/GamesServerAuthCodeOp(5775): com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedPermission
```

Finnaly, the best I was able to achieve is to get 'only' the "View your basic profile info" permission doing this:

```
Scope scope = new Scope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this, this, this)
    .addApi(Games.API)
    .addScope(scope)
    .build();
```

So to recap - I want to get the server authorization code using 9.6.1 without being prompted for any extra permissions (like in the 2017 article using 10.2.1 using `DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN`).

Are there any scopes I can use that will give me the server authorization code (to get the playerId) without requesting extra permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. The scope you're already using is the right (and the simplest) way to retrieve an auth code and at the same time get a `playerId`.

Comment: Thanks AL. - I also noticed that in Google's My Account / Connected apps & sites older apps all required those permissions, but new ones don't.